# Mantener los decimales

Tags: javascript

Quiero mantener los decimales, tengo un numero largo `120.29998999867869` y lo quiero cortar con 5 decimales, el resultado deseado es `120.299998`, el siguiente codigo lo intento pero obtengo `120.30000`

```js
let num = 120.29999999867869;
console.log(num.toFixed(5));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el ejemplo que estás dando, el redondeo se hace hacia `.30000` ya que no es el mismo número que planteas en la pregunta.

Si querés que los decimales se vean sin que se haga el redondeo, podés hacer lo siguiente:

```
let num = 120.29999999867869;
num.toString().split('.')[0] + '.' + num.toString().split('.')[1].substring(0,5);
```

Sin embargo, es una solución *no tan atractiva*.

Te incluyo ejemplos:

```js
// Número usado en la pregunta
let num1 = 120.29998999867869
console.log('Numero usado en la pregunta: ' + num1.toFixed(5));

// Número usado en el ejemplo
let num2 = 120.29999999867869;
console.log('Numero usado en el ejemplo: ' + num2.toFixed(5));
console.log('Numero usado en el ejemplo (con split y substring): ' + num2.toString().split('.')[0] + '.' + num2.toString().split('.')[1].substring(0,5));
```